# Передача значения переменной в запрос из программы на с++ в базу данных, написанной на Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, c++

Пишу программу на с++, которая обращается к базе данных, созданной в Postgresql.
Хочу, чтобы значение для заполнения некого столбца одной из таблиц задавалось не в самом запросе, а через переменную. Возникает вопрос: как передать значение этой переменной в запрос?

```
int m;
m=rand()%100;
res = PQexec(conn, "insert into Таблица (Значение) values (&m);");
```

Comment: то есть, проблема в том, как преобразовать число в строку и потом сделать конткатенацию?

Comment: проблема в том, как передать значение параметра m в sql-запрос.
как я написала: код не работает именно на месте передачи параметра m в запрос sql.

Comment: если вместо m поставить просто любое число, запрос отлично работает.

Comment: поучить бы базовых вещей...

по старинке я бы сделал где то так

    int m;
    m=rand()%100;
    char sqlreq[400];
    sprintf(sqlreq, "insert into Таблица (Значение) values (%d);", m);
    res = PQexec(conn, sqlreq);

Но лучше внимательно почитать документацию. В многих движках есть поддержка параметров.

Почитал [документацию](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-example.html). Вместо PQExec используйте PQExecParams, он умеет подставлять параметры.

Comment: Спасибо.
Да, я тоже находила функцию PQExecParams, но я не сильна в английском и не поняла, как ей пользоваться. Русскоязычного описания этой функции я не нашла.
А как нам из базы данных извлечь значение и записать его в переменную?..

Comment: По приведенной выше же ссылке в коде найдите функцию `show_binary_results`. Там есть использование функции `PQgetvalue`. Как раз она Вам и нужна.